# Creating excel macro to take info from form and append it onto bottom of list

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a spreadsheet to help track individuals who attend a weekly meeting conducted by my department. I am trying to automate the process of tracking by using a macro to copy values from a list/form that a member of my department will enter the attendees email and the date. The email and date will then be added together (=a&b) to generate a value and that value will be used to mark whether the individual is present or not at that particular meeting. View Image of form/table

[image]

A report is generated after the meeting to tell which individuals have attended and how long they were on the call for. Before I was taking this report and pasting it onto the bottom of the original list but this has become inefficient as the columns and table length have changed.  What I would like to do is take the emails, dates, and value on spreadsheet from the calculate tab and have those values append onto the bottom of the list on the reports tab without altering any of the previous information. View Image of reports tab

[image]

After the values have been appended to the bottom of the report, I have another tab called meeting dates. This contains a formula that will determine whether the individual was present or not by marking it with either “Y” or “N”. Forgot to mention that every week it is the same 17 individuals that are attending these meetings.  Eventually I would like to have it so that if the date entered on the calculate tab is not present on the meeting dates tab, add the date to the meeting dates tab.

I am still very new to Excel VB and macros however do have some programming experience. Just not in excel. If somebody could help me, that would be awesome!

Comment: Are you asking to get the code for the above? Please read the help section and adjust your question accordingly.

Comment: FeliceM-  Yeah it would be awesome if I could get the code or if somebody could walk me thru it. Please keep in mind that this is not an open ended question.

Comment: Thats just the thing. I have no idea where to start. I've been searching all over the internet and have tried to implement but no dice... I've also tried to use the record but it pastes over values that are already present in the list where I would like to add onto the list.

Comment: Note that I pointed you to help section because questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.  SO is not a site where members code other people applications.

Comment: I understand that. And I appreciate your response. That is exactly why I have come to SO with hopes that someone could guide me in the right direction. I have been stuck with this problem for over a week and it's really starting to frustrate me. I appreciate any and every bit of help

Answer (score 2):

This answer is an attempt to get your started.

If you search the internet for "Excel VBA Tutorial" you will get many hits.  Try a few because they are all different and pick the one you like best.  Work through that tutorial to get a general feel for Excel.  I do not believe you will be successful finding bits of relevant code without that general feel.

Do not try to describe your entire problem because I doubt anyone will respond.  Instead try to break your problem down into little steps and seek help with those steps.

For example, you will need to determine the number of rows in the post-meeting report so you can access that data.  You then want to add that data to the bottom of the previous list.  In both cases you need to determine the last used row in a worksheet.  "Excel VBA: How to find last row of worksheet?" is a simple question and you will be able to find multiple answers.  I give my response to that question below.

I assume the post-meeting report and the list you are creating are in different workbooks.  Your macro could be in the same workbook as the list or it could be in a different workbook.  Macros can access their own workbooks, any other workbook that happens to be open or they can open as many other workbooks as required.  Again "Excel VBA: How do I work with several workbooks?" should result in plenty of hits.

I have not tried either of my questions.  I find "Excel VBA:" helps but you may require several attempts before you find the just the right question to get the answer you seek.  But if your question is small and precise you should always be able to find an answer.

Let's return to the first question.  An irritating feature of Excel VBA is that they are almost always several ways of achieving a similar effect.  Create a new workbook, create a module and copy the code below to it.  Run the macro `FindFinal()`.

This macro demonstrates several methods of finding the last row and column.  Every method has its problems and I have tried to show how how each method can fail.  There is a lot of worksheet access within this macro which I believe will repay study.  It should help you decide which method is appropriate for each of your requirements.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindFinal()

  Dim Col As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim Row As Long

  ' Try the various techniques on an empty worksheet
  Debug.Print "***** Empty worksheet"
  Debug.Print ""

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete

    Set Rng = .UsedRange
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "Used range is Nothing"
    Else
      Debug.Print "Top row of used range is: " & Rng.Row
      Debug.Print "Left column row of used range is: " & Rng.Column
      Debug.Print "Number of rows in used range is: " & Rng.Rows.Count
      Debug.Print "Number of columns in used range is: " & Rng.Columns.Count
      Debug.Print "!!! Notice that the worksheet is empty but the user range is not."
    End If

    Debug.Print ""

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "According to Find the worksheet is empty"
    Else
      Debug.Print "According to Find the last row containing a value is: " & Rng.Row
    End If

    Debug.Print ""
    Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "According to SpecialCells the worksheet is empty"
    Else
      Debug.Print "According to SpecialCells the last row is: " & Rng.Row
      Debug.Print "According to SpecialCells the last column is: " & Rng.Column
    End If

    Debug.Print ""
    Row = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Debug.Print "Down from A1 goes to: A" & Row
    Row = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print "up from A" & Rows.Count & " goes to: A" & Row
    Col = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    Debug.Print "Right from A1 goes to: " & ColNumToCode(Col) & "1"
    Col = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Debug.Print "Left from " & Columns.Count & _
                "1 goes to: " & ColNumToCode(Col) & "1"

    ' Add some values and formatting to worksheet

    .Range("A1").Value = "A1"
    .Range("A2").Value = "A2"
    For Row = 5 To 7
      .Cells(Row, "A").Value = "A" & Row
    Next
    For Row = 12 To 15
      .Cells(Row, 1).Value = "A" & Row
    Next

    .Range("B1").Value = "B1"
    .Range("C2").Value = "C2"
    .Range("B16").Value = "B6"
    .Range("C17").Value = "C17"

    .Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 5
    .Cells(18, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 255)
    .Rows(19).RowHeight = 5

    Debug.Print ""
    Debug.Print "***** Non-empty worksheet"
    Debug.Print ""

    Set Rng = .UsedRange
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "Used range is Nothing"
    Else
      Debug.Print "Top row of used range is: " & Rng.Row
      Debug.Print "Left column row of used range is: " & Rng.Column
      Debug.Print "Number of rows in used range is: " & Rng.Rows.Count
      Debug.Print "Number of columns in used range is: " & Rng.Columns.Count
      Debug.Print "!!! Notice that row 19 which is empty but has had its height changed is ""used""."
      Debug.Print "!!! Notice that column 5 which is empty but has had its width changed is not ""used""."
      Debug.Print "!!! Notice that column 4 which is empty but contains a coloured cell is ""used""."
    End If

    Debug.Print ""

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "According to Find the worksheet is empty"
    Else
      Debug.Print "According to Find the last row containing a formula is: " & Rng.Row
    End If
    ' *** Note: search by columns not search by rows ***
    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "According to Find the worksheet is empty"
    Else
      Debug.Print "According to Find the last column containing a formula is: " & Rng.Column
    End If
    ' *** Note: Find returns a single cell and the nature of the search
    '           affects what it find.  Compare SpecialCells below.

    Debug.Print ""
    Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "According to SpecialCells the worksheet is empty"
    Else
      Debug.Print "According to SpecialCells the last row is: " & Rng.Row
      Debug.Print "According to SpecialCells the last column is: " & Rng.Column
    End If

    Debug.Print ""
    Row = 1
    Do While True
      Debug.Print "Down from A" & Row & " goes to: ";
      Row = .Cells(Row, 1).End(xlDown).Row
      Debug.Print "A" & Row
      If Row = Rows.Count Then Exit Do
    Loop

  End With

  With Worksheets("Sheet2")

    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete

  .Range("B2").Value = "B2"
  .Range("C3").Value = "C3"
  .Range("B7").Value = "B7"
  .Range("B7:B8").Merge
  .Range("F3").Value = "F3"
  .Range("F3:G3").Merge

    Debug.Print ""
    Debug.Print "***** Try with merged cells"

    Set Rng = .UsedRange
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "Used range is Nothing"
    Else
      Debug.Print "Used range is: " & Replace(Rng.Address, "$", "")
    End If

    Debug.Print ""
    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "According to Find the worksheet is empty"
    Else
      Debug.Print "According to Find the last cell by row is: " & Replace(Rng.Address, "$", "")
    End If
    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "According to Find the worksheet is empty"
    Else
      Debug.Print "According to Find the last cell by column is: " & Replace(Rng.Address, "$", "")
    End If
      Debug.Print "!!! Notice that Find can ""see"" B7 but not F3."

    Debug.Print ""
    Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "According to SpecialCells the worksheet is empty"
    Else
      Debug.Print "According to SpecialCells the last row is: " & Rng.Row
      Debug.Print "According to SpecialCells the last column is: " & Rng.Column
    End If

  End With

End Sub
Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  Dim Code As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  ' Last updated 3 Feb 12.  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  If ColNum = 0 Then
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    Code = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      Code = Chr(65 + PartNum) & Code
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

End Function
```

In the code above, I access worksheet cells directly with statements such as `.Range("B2").Value = "B2"`.  This can be slow particularly when you are moving data from one worksheet to another.  An alternative approach is to use arrays.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ShtValues as Variant

With Worksheets("Xxxx")
  Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(Row1, Col1), .Cells(Row2, Col2))
End With 

ShtValues = Rng.Value
```

A Variant is a variable that can hold anything including an array.  `ShtValues = Rng.Value` converts `ShtValues` to a two-dimensional array hold all the values within Rng.  Processing values within an array is much faster that accessing them in the worksheet.

`.Range(.Cells(Row1, Col1), .Cells(Row2, Col2))` is perhaps the easiest way of creating a range specifying the worksheet area with Cells(Row1, Col1) as the top left cell and Cells(Row2, Col2) as the bottom right.

If I understand correctly, you want to move data from the post-meeting report to the list but the sequence of columns in the report and list are not the same.  This suggests you need to move the data as columns.  Using `.Range(.Cells(Row1, Col1), .Cells(Row2, Col2))` and with Col1 = Col2, you can define a range that is a column.

```
Rng1.Copy Destination := Cell2
```

The above statement will copy the contents of Rng1 to the range starting at Cell2.  A statement like this for each column of data in the report may be the easiest way of copying the data.

I hope the above gives you a start.