# Maximum value of each column from a dynamic range

Tags: excel, dynamic, range, vba

I have "sheet 1" with raw data. The number of rows and columns is always different. The columns show temperatures varying function of time. As is showed:

ColumnA (time) 0.000/Column B (TC1) 27.342/Column C (TC2) 26.409/Column D (TC3)  ...etc.

I would like to find the maximum value in each temperature column and copy and paste them transpose on "sheet2", pasting also its first row, and matching the peak temp with its row, as is showed below:

TC1  305.387(max value) 354 (row)/TC2 409.989(max value) 575 (row)/TC3 789.383(max temp) 899(row)...etc.

The point is that I'm using my own range...each time that I use the code I choose different range, sometimes includes all the rows and some columns, other times some rows and all columns, etc. Below is myRange code:

```
Public Sub run_CalcPeakTemp()
Dim myCalRange As Range
Dim iReply As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Set myCalcRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select first row and then Ctrl+Shift+down", Title:="Select Range", Type:=8)
myCalcRange.Select
If myCalcRange Is Nothing Then
iReply = MsgBox("Range not selected!")
Exit Sub
If myCalcRange Is notNothing Then
Call run_CalcPeakTemp
End If
End If
```

And here is where I'm stuck...I'm not able of doing it in a loop. I did badly a too basic like that...step by step...I'm a beginner :(

```
Dim VarMaxVal As Variant
VarMaxVal = 0
VarMaxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns(1))
Sheets("Calc").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = VarMaxVal
```

And so on the rest of the columns.

.....Nether I was able of copy the first row of my dynamic range selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a "do this and all will be well" answer because I do not quite understand what you are attempting.  However, I hope this answer includes enough pointers for you to create the code you seek.

**Issue 1**

You are absolutely correct to use a worksheet function rather than your own VBA when a suitable worksheet function exists since the worksheet function will be substantially faster.  However, if there is any way of getting the Max function to return the row, I do not know it.  I believe you will have to use VBA to scan each column.

**Issue 2**

`On Error Resume Next` should never be used like this since all errors will be ignored.  Ideally you avoid errors by checking in advance.  If you want to open a file, you should check it exists before attempting the open rather than wait for the open to fail and give an error.  However, there are some situations in which you cannot check for an error.  In such situations you can use `On Error Resume Next` so:

```
  Err.Clear
  On Error Resume Next
  ' Statement that might fail
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ' Statement failed.
    ' Description of failure in Err.Description.
    ' Report error with user friendly message and exit or take corrective action.
  End If
```

**Issue 3**

Please indent your code so it is easier to read and spot errors.  For example:

```
 1 Public Sub run_CalcPeakTemp()
 2   Dim myCalRange As Range
 3   Dim iReply As Integer
 4   'On Error Resume Next
 5   Set myCalcRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select first row and then Ctrl+Shift+down", _
 6                    Title:="Select Range", Type:=8)
 7   myCalcRange.Select
 8   If myCalcRange Is Nothing Then
 9     iReply = MsgBox("Range not selected!")
10     Exit Sub
11     If myCalcRange Is notNothing Then
12       Call run_CalcPeakTemp
13     End If
14   End If
15 End Sub
```

I have added the line numbers so I can reference statements easily.  I have also split line 5 over two lines so most of it is visible.

**Issue 4**

On line 2, you declare `myCalRange`.  Elsewhere within the routine you use `myCalcRange`.  If the first statement of your module is `Option Explicit`, you will be told at compile time that `myCalcRange` has not been declared.  If you omit `Option Explicit`, the first reference to `myCalcRange` will perform an implicit declaration.  Detecting implicit declarations can be very difficult.  Always include `Option Explicit`.

**Issue 5**

Line 11 should be `If Not myCalcRange Is Nothing Then`.  VBA does not have an IsNot operator and the space was in the wrong place.

**Issue 6**

I have never used InputBox in this way and I find the help misleading:

- Set myRange = Application.InputBox(prompt := "Sample", type := 8)
- If you don't use the Set statement, the variable is set to the value in the range, rather than the Range object itself.

If `myRange` is declared as a `Range` then the `Set` is compulsory.  If `myRange` is declared as a `Variant` then the `Set` is forbidden.  If `myRange` is not declared and you rely on an inplicit declaration then `myRange` will be declared as a `Range` if you include `Set` and a `Variant` if you omit it.

This is not your mistake.  This feature(?) of VBA is at least 11 years old and I can only assume someone thought they were being helpful.

**Issue 7**

```
 7   myCalcRange.Select
 8   If myCalcRange Is Nothing Then
```

You cannot select a range that is Nothing.  The test must come first.

**Issue 8**

```
 8   If myCalcRange Is Nothing Then
 9     iReply = MsgBox("Range not selected!")
10     Exit Sub
11     If myCalcRange Is notNothing Then
12       Call run_CalcPeakTemp
13     End If
14   End If
```

With the indenting you can see that all this code is within the first `If`.  I am not sure if this is what you wanted.  Did you mean?

```
 8   If myCalcRange Is Nothing Then
 9     iReply = MsgBox("Range not selected!")
10     Exit Sub
14   End If
11   If myCalcRange Is notNothing Then
12     Call run_CalcPeakTemp
13   End If
```

I assume you are trying to force the user to select a range.  In general, you should allow the user some way of cancelling a selection.  In theory, to force the user to make a selection you need something like:

```
    Set myCalcRange = Nothing
    Do While myCalcRange Is Nothing
       Set myCalcRange = Application.InputBox ...
    Loop
```

In practice, InputBox will not permit the user to click <kbd>OK</kbd> unless a range has been selected and clicking <kbd>Cancel</kbd> gives a VBA error.  `InputBox( ... type := 8)` is not a statement I would ever use!

**Issue 9**

```
12     Call run_CalcPeakTemp
```

A routine calling itself is called recursion and is permitted by VBA but it cannot be used in this way.  One possible use is to search down a hierarchy and get the value at the bottom.  The routine checks for being at the bottom of the hierarchy.  If it is, it returns the value.  If it is not, it calls itself with the next level down as its parameter.

This is the VBA equivalent of a simple use of recursion I was taught many years ago:

```
Function Factorial(ByVal N As Long) As Long
  If N = 1 Then
    Factorial = 1
  Else
    Factorial = N * Factorial(N - 1)
  End If
End Function
```

This routine:

```
Sub Test()
  Debug.Print "Factorial(1) = " & Factorial(1)
  Debug.Print "Factorial(2) = " & Factorial(2)
  Debug.Print "Factorial(3) = " & Factorial(3)
  Debug.Print "Factorial(4) = " & Factorial(4)
  Debug.Print "Factorial(5) = " & Factorial(5)
End Sub
```

displays the following in the immediate window:

```
Factorial(1) = 1
Factorial(2) = 2
Factorial(3) = 6
Factorial(4) = 24
Factorial(5) = 120
```

**Some code that might be useful**

This code matches my guess of your requirement.

I say little about the syntax of VBA I have used.  In general once you know a statement exists, it is easy to look it up but ask if necessary.

I have tried explained what I am doing.  I have tried to make my code as general and as maintainable as I can.  There is a lot here but if you work slowly down the code I believe you will grasp what each section is doing.  Again ask if necessary.

I think learning programming is like learning to driving a car.  At the end of your first lesson you know you will NEVER be able to work three pedals, a gear stick, a wheel and an indicator while checking the mirror.  Yet a month later you cannot remember why you found it so difficult.  Welcome to the joys of programming.  I hope you find it as much fun as I do.

```
Sub ExtractMaxTemperatures()

  ' I understand your temperatures are in columns 2 to 5.  If I use these values
  ' in the code and they change (perhaps because new columns are added) then you
  ' will have to search the code for the appropriate 2s and 5s and replace them.
  ' Constants allow me to use names which makes the code easier to understand.
  ' Also if the column numbers change, change the constants and the code is fixed.

  ' I have used Sheet1 to hold the full set of temperatures and Sheet2 to hold the
  ' extracted maximums.  In these constants, and in the variables below, replacing
  ' "Sht1" and "Sht2" with something more meaningful will help make the code more
  ' readable.
  Const ColSht1TempFirst As Long = 2
  Const ColSht1TempLast As Long = 5
  Const RowSht1DataFirst As Long = 3
  Const ColSht2Dest As Long = 2
  Const RowSht2Dest As Long = 3

  Dim ColSht1Crnt As Long
  Dim RowSht1Crnt As Long
  Dim ColSht2Crnt As Long
  Dim RowSht2Crnt As Long

  ' Declare fixed size arrays to hold the maximum temperature
  ' and its row for each column
  Dim TempMaxByCol(ColSht1TempFirst To ColSht1TempLast) As Single
  Dim RowForMaxTemp(ColSht1TempFirst To ColSht1TempLast) As Long

  Dim TempCrnt As Single
  Dim TempMaxCrnt As Single
  Dim RowForMaxCrnt As Long

  Dim ShtValue As Variant

  ' It is possible to check the values within the worksheet with statements
  ' such as "If .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = 5 Then"
  ' However, it is much quicker to copy all values from the worksheet to an
  ' array and process the values from the array.  I have done this since I
  ' will have to use arrays within the column loop.

  ' I do not know the name of the worksheet containing the temperatue so I have
  ' used Sheet1.

  ' The statement "ShtValues = .UsedRange.Value" converts ShtValues to a two
  ' dimensional array containing every value in in the worksheet.  The rows
  ' are dimension 1 and the columns are dimension 2 which is not the usual
  ' arrangement.  However, it means "ShtValue(RowCrnt, ColCrnt)" matches
  ' ".Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value" which avoids confusion.

  ' Because I have loaded the entire worksheet, row and column numbers within
  ' the array will match those in the worksheet.

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ShtValue = .UsedRange.Value
  End With

  ' Loop for each temperature column
  For ColSht1Crnt = ColSht1TempFirst To ColSht1TempLast

    ' Your code assume no blank or non-numeric values within the temperature
    ' ranges.  However, were they to exist, the code would fail so I check.

    RowForMaxCrnt = 0           ' Indicates no temperature saved yet

      ' Loop for each data row column.  UBound(ShtValue, 2) identifies the last row.
      For RowSht1Crnt = RowSht1DataFirst To UBound(ShtValue, 1)
        If IsNumeric(ShtValue(RowSht1Crnt, ColSht1Crnt)) Then
          ' This cell is numeric
          TempCrnt = Val(ShtValue(RowSht1Crnt, ColSht1Crnt))
          If RowForMaxCrnt <> 0 Then
            ' A possible maximum temperature has already been stored.
            ' Check current value against it.
            If TempMaxCrnt < TempCrnt Then
              ' Higher temperature found.  Store details in temporary variables
              RowForMaxCrnt = RowSht1Crnt
              TempMaxCrnt = TempCrnt
            End If
          Else
            ' First temperature found.  Store details in temporary variables
            RowForMaxCrnt = RowSht1Crnt
            TempMaxCrnt = TempCrnt
          End If
        End If
      Next
      'Store values in temporary variable in arrays
      TempMaxByCol(ColSht1Crnt) = TempMaxCrnt
      RowForMaxTemp(ColSht1Crnt) = RowForMaxCrnt

  Next

  ' Initialise the current row to the start row of the outout table
  RowSht2Crnt = RowSht2Dest

  ' I think you call the destination sheet "Calc" but I have used "Sheet2"

  With Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ' Create header lines
    '    TC1       TC2       TC3       TC4
    ' Max  Row  Max  Row  Max  Row  Max  Row

    ' This code will handle multiple header rows
    For RowSht1Crnt = 1 To RowSht1DataFirst - 1
      ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Dest
      For ColSht1Crnt = ColSht1TempFirst To ColSht1TempLast
        ' Merge two cells together ready for column name
        .Range(.Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt), _
               .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt + 1)).Merge
        With .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt)
          .Value = ShtValue(RowSht1Crnt, ColSht1Crnt)
          .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Crnt + 2
      Next
      RowSht2Crnt = RowSht2Crnt + 1
    Next
    ' Now add "Max  Row  Max  Row  Max  Row  Max  Row" row
    ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Dest
    For ColSht1Crnt = ColSht1TempFirst To ColSht1TempLast
      With .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt)
        .Value = "Max"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
      End With
      ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Crnt + 1
      With .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt)
        .Value = "Row"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
      End With
      ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Crnt + 1
    Next
    RowSht2Crnt = RowSht2Crnt + 1

    ' Now create data row
    ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Dest
    For ColSht1Crnt = ColSht1TempFirst To ColSht1TempLast
      .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt).Value = TempMaxByCol(ColSht1Crnt)
      ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Crnt + 1
      .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt).Value = RowForMaxTemp(ColSht1Crnt)
      ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Crnt + 1
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

**Edit**  Addition because OP wants to select columns from which maximums are to be selected.

If I understand your comment correctly:

- The number of rows is fixed at 30.
- You wish to select the columns from which the maximums are to be extracted at run-time.

The code above will handle any number of rows.  I suggest you leave this unchanged even if you believe the number will always be 30.  During my career I heard "that requirement could never change" many times only to hear a year or two later "Sorry, it has changed."

There was one aspect of the code above which I thought was weak but which I did not want to correct because it would have added complications that did not want to explain.  I used `.UsedRange` to load data from the worksheet.  This is the easiest method but the definition of `.UsedRange` does not always match what the user expects. `.UsedRange` includes rows and columns that have been formatted (eg height or width changed) but are otherwise unused.  In this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20849875/973283) to an earlier question I include a macro which demonstrates a number of techniques for finding the final row or column and show where each method fails.  I do not think this is important for your current question but I suggest you save that macro and experiment with it later.

Consider this macro:

```
Sub TestGetRange()

  Dim CalcRange As Range
  Dim Reply As Long

  Do While True
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    Set CalcRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select columns to be copied", _
                                         Title:="Extract maximum temperatures", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Reply = MsgBox(Prompt:="Do you wish to exit without extracting any temperatures?", _
                     Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Extract maximum temperatures")
      If Reply = vbYes Then
        ' User wants to exit
        Exit Do
      End If
      ' Loop for another go
    Else
      ' User had entered a valid range
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

  If CalcRange Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "User wants immediate exit"
    Exit Sub
  Else
    Debug.Print CalcRange.Address
  End If

End Sub
```

As I said earlier, if the user clicks <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, there is a run time syntax error and the user has to select <kbd>Debug</kbd> and click <kbd>F5</kbd> to continue.  This is the type of situation for which `On Error Resume Next` is appropriate.  I have added this to your original code and have included an option to exit.  This macro does not use the entered range other than to display its address.

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Mouse</kbd> you can select non-contiguous ranges.  You do not say if you want to be able to select columns 4, 5, 11 and 12 but, since you cannot stop the user selecting non-contiguous ranges, I have included the code to handle them.

I ran this macro a number of times.  The first time I selected columns B and C, the next time I cancelled then I selected various mixed ranges.  The output was:

```
$B:$C
User wants immediate exit
$B$1,$D$1
$B$1,$C$1,$E$1
$B$1:$D$1
$B:$B,$E:$E
$B:$C,$E:$E,$F:$F,$H:$H
$B:$B,$E$2
```

Notice that I get `$B:$B` or `$B:$C` if I select columns and `$E$1` if I select a cell.  In the last row I have selected both a column and a cell.

Have a play with this macro and get a feel for ranges that it can get from the user.

Somehow you need to convert the range obtained from the user into one or more columns.

Add this code to the bottom of the above macro:

```
  Dim Count As Long
  Dim RngCrnt As Range

  Count = 0
  For Each RngCrnt In CalcRange
    Debug.Print "  " & RngCrnt.Address
    Count = Count + 1
    If Count = 10 Then
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  Debug.Print CalcRange.EntireColumn.Address
  For Each RngCrnt In CalcRange.EntireColumn
    Debug.Print "  " & RngCrnt.Address
    Count = Count + 1
    If Count = 10 Then
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
```

In this code I have used the `For Each` statement to split the range from the user into sub-ranges.  I ran the macro, selected columns B and C and got the following output:

```
$B:$C
  $B$1
  $C$1
  $B$2
  $C$2
  $B$3
  $C$3
  $B$4
  $C$4
  $B$5
  $C$5
$B:$C
  $B:$B
  $C:$C
```

With the first `For Next`, the sub-range is a cell.  If I had omitted the code limiting the output to 10, I would have got one display row per cell in each column.

In the second `For Next`, I have adjusted the user's range by adding `.EntireColumn`.  This has no effect on the address as displayed by `Debug.Print CalcRange.EntireColumn.Address` but has changed the sub-range to a column which is what I want.

I think that is all the new information you need to understand the revised macro.  I was hoping to give you a list of changes but there are too many little changes to make that practical.

```
Sub ExtractMaxTemperatures2()

  ' Adjusted to handle user selected columns

  Const RowSht1DataFirst As Long = 2    ' First non-header row in Sheet1
  Const ColSht2Dest As Long = 2         ' Left column \  of table of extracted
  Const RowSht2Dest As Long = 3         ' Top row     /   values in Sheet2

  Dim ColLogicalCrnt As Long            ' 1, 2, 3 and so on regardless of true column number
  Dim ColSht1Crnt As Long               ' Current column within Sheet1
  Dim ColSht2Crnt As Long               ' Current column within Sheet2
  Dim NumColsSelected As Long           ' Number of columns selected.
  Dim Reply As Long                     ' Return value from InputBox
  Dim RowForMaxCrnt As Long             ' Row holding maximum temperature found so far within current column
  Dim RowSht1Crnt As Long               ' Current row within Sheet1
  Dim RowSht2Crnt As Long               ' Current row within Sheet2
  Dim RngColCrnt As Range               ' Sub-range of user selected range giving current column
  Dim RngUserSelected                   ' Range selected by user then adjusted with .EntireColumn
  Dim ShtValue As Variant               ' 2D array holding values loaded from Sheet1
  Dim TempCrnt As Single                ' The temperature from the current cell
  Dim TempMaxCrnt As Single             ' Maximum temperature found so far within current column

  ' Declare arrays to hold the maximum temperature and its row for each column.
  ' These arrays will be sized at runtime.
  Dim TempMaxByCol() As Single          ' Maximum temperature for each logical column
  Dim RowForMaxTemp() As Long           ' Row for maximum temperature for each logical column

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ShtValue = .UsedRange.Value
    .Activate       ' Necessary to ensure Sheet1 visible for range selection
  End With

  Do While True
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RngUserSelected = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select columns to be copied", _
                                         Title:="Extract maximum temperatures", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Reply = MsgBox(Prompt:="Do you wish to exit without extracting any temperatures?", _
                     Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Extract maximum temperatures")
      If Reply = vbYes Then
        ' User wants to exit
        Exit Do
      End If
      ' Loop for another go
    Else
      ' User had entered a valid range
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

  If RngUserSelected Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "User wants immediate exit"
  End If

  ' Convert any cells to columns
  Set RngUserSelected = RngUserSelected.EntireColumn

  ' Count number of selected columns
  NumColsSelected = 0
  For Each RngColCrnt In RngUserSelected
    NumColsSelected = NumColsSelected + 1
  Next

  ' Size arrays for number of selected columns
  ReDim TempMaxByCol(1 To NumColsSelected) As Single
  ReDim RowForMaxTemp(1 To NumColsSelected) As Long

  ' Fill TempMaxByCol and RowForMaxTemp with extracted values
  ColLogicalCrnt = 0

  ' Loop for each temperature column
  For Each RngColCrnt In RngUserSelected

    ColSht1Crnt = RngColCrnt.Column
    ColLogicalCrnt = ColLogicalCrnt + 1    ' Logical column for this physical column

    RowForMaxCrnt = 0           ' Indicates no temperature saved yet

      ' Loop for each data row column.  UBound(ShtValue, 2) identifies the last row.
      For RowSht1Crnt = RowSht1DataFirst To UBound(ShtValue, 1)
        If IsNumeric(ShtValue(RowSht1Crnt, ColSht1Crnt)) Then
          ' This cell is numeric
          TempCrnt = Val(ShtValue(RowSht1Crnt, ColSht1Crnt))
          If RowForMaxCrnt <> 0 Then
            ' A possible maximum temperature has already been stored.
            ' Check current value against it.
            If TempMaxCrnt < TempCrnt Then
              ' Higher temperature found.  Store details in temporary variables
              RowForMaxCrnt = RowSht1Crnt
              TempMaxCrnt = TempCrnt
            End If
          Else
            ' First temperature found.  Store details in temporary variables
            RowForMaxCrnt = RowSht1Crnt
            TempMaxCrnt = TempCrnt
          End If
        End If
      Next
      'Move values from temporary variables to arrays
      TempMaxByCol(ColLogicalCrnt) = TempMaxCrnt
      RowForMaxTemp(ColLogicalCrnt) = RowForMaxCrnt

  Next

  ' Initialise the current row to the start row of the outout table
  RowSht2Crnt = RowSht2Dest

  ' I think you call the destination sheet "Calc" but I have used "Sheet2"

  With Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ' Create header lines
    '    TC1       TC2       TC3       TC4
    ' Max  Row  Max  Row  Max  Row  Max  Row

    ' This code will handle multiple header rows
    For RowSht1Crnt = 1 To RowSht1DataFirst - 1
      ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Dest
      ColLogicalCrnt = 0
      For Each RngColCrnt In RngUserSelected
        ColSht1Crnt = RngColCrnt.Column
        ColLogicalCrnt = ColLogicalCrnt + 1    ' Logical column for this physical column
        ' Merge two cells together ready for column name
        .Range(.Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt), _
               .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt + 1)).Merge
        With .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt)
          .Value = ShtValue(RowSht1Crnt, ColSht1Crnt)
          .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Crnt + 2
      Next
      RowSht2Crnt = RowSht2Crnt + 1
    Next
    ' Now add "Max  Row  Max  Row  Max  Row  Max  Row" row
    ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Dest
    ' ColLogicalCrnt = 0        ' Don't need logical column for this loop
     For Each RngColCrnt In RngUserSelected
      ColSht1Crnt = RngColCrnt.Column
      With .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt)
        .Value = "Max"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
      End With
      ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Crnt + 1
      With .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt)
        .Value = "Row"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
      End With
      ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Crnt + 1
    Next
    RowSht2Crnt = RowSht2Crnt + 1

    ' Now create data row
    ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Dest
    ColLogicalCrnt = 0

    ' Loop for each temperature column
    For Each RngColCrnt In RngUserSelected
      ' ColSht1Crnt = RngColCrnt.Column    ' Don't need Sheet 1 column for this loop
      ColLogicalCrnt = ColLogicalCrnt + 1    ' Logical column for this physical column
      .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt).Value = TempMaxByCol(ColLogicalCrnt)
      ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Crnt + 1
      .Cells(RowSht2Crnt, ColSht2Crnt).Value = RowForMaxTemp(ColLogicalCrnt)
      ColSht2Crnt = ColSht2Crnt + 1
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks Tony!, it has been very instructive. I'm pleased that you have help me not only answering the question but also teaching me. Reading your answer I see that I have a long long long way to go...Apologize for not expressing myself clearly, English is not my mother tongue and my knowledge are to basic in vb.

Comment: Regarding the code, you got almost all what I wanted to do but one of my problems is that I never use the same number of columns. Row data always contents the same number of them (30) but I don't want to show all of them in "sheet2" , just the ones that I need sometimes 10 other 12, etc. This is why I wanted to select manually the range before. But not even know if that's possible to do. Cheers

Comment: I have forgotten the little non-English I ever knew so cannot criticise anyone.  Your English was fine.  It can be difficult to explain exactly what you want even in your own language.

Comment: I will think about your second comment.  I have a couple of ideas and will come back later when I have tried them.

Comment: @Jero.  I do not know if you are told if an answer is updated so this comment is to force the sending of a message.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that... Thank you for letting me know. I'll check out everything on Monday. I am away this WE, not working :). I just can say that I try and it works perfectly. I'll answer you on Monday after studying properly your code. I'm pretty impressed. Thank you very much.